# Which is better for scalability multiple database or NoSql?

Tags: database, oracle, web-applications, nosql, scalability

For an existing web application built on using Oracle database, what are the choices available in order to scale horizontally. Few thoughts are:

1. Have multiple databases and multiple application servers each connecting to a different database and a controller application with his own database whose role will be to decide which request to send to which server. Challenges involve moving existing data from one database to another as and when required in order to evenly distribute the load on multiple databases. Also keeping all the common data on all the database in sync with the controller database.
2. Move to NoSql
3. Any other?
   Please suggest.

Comment: Oracle RAC is the standard approach to horizontal scaling.  Is there a reason that you don't list that option (i.e. cost)?  What is the current bottleneck?

Comment: I dont know about the cost of using Oracle RAC, can you pls give me some overview about the cost comparison of going to Oracle RAC or to NoSql or any other solution.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information about your current setup, what the bottlenecks are, and so forth if you want to get an answer more detailed than Justin Cave's.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach to horizontally scaling an Oracle database is to use [Oracle Real Application Clusters (RAC)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/clustering/overview/index.html).  RAC allows you to have a single database on a shared file system (i.e. a NAS or a SAN) that is mounted by multiple different instances running on multiple different database servers simultaneously.  Oracle takes care of keeping the data in the caches of the various nodes in sync.

If you are using the enterprise edition of Oracle, RAC is an extra-cost option (you'd need to speak to your Oracle Sales rep to get a quote).  RAC is included with the standard edition (though the number and size of machines you can have in a standard edition RAC cluster is limited).